# Angular 5 & .NET Core 2.0 - router navigate freeze website

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5, angular-routing

I am learning Angular 5 and implementing simple application (on back-end side I am using .net core 2.0 web api). After user clicks delete button on modal I am trying to make redirection to home page, and redirection is being made but whole page freeze. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

template

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModalCenter">
        Delete settle
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalCenterTitle">Permanently delete settle "{{ settle.name }}"</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              Are you sure you want to delete this kitty and all its data?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteSettle()">Delete</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

component

```
  deleteSettle(): void {
    this.settleService
      .deleteSettle(this.settle.id)
      .subscribe(() => this.logicAfterSettleDelete())
  }

  private logicAfterSettleDelete() {
    console.log(`Settle with id: ${this.settle.id} deleted!`);

    this.router.navigate([``]); // after this redirection page freeze
  }
```

app-routing.module

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {CreateComponent} from "./create/create.component";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home.component";
import {SettleComponent} from "./settle/settle.component";
import {EditSettleComponent} from "./edit-settle/edit-settle.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'create', component: CreateComponent},
  {path: 'blog', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'faq', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'settle/:id', component: SettleComponent},
  {path: 'edit/:id', component: EditSettleComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

settleService

```
  deleteSettle(id: number): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.delete<number>(`${this.settleUrl}/${id}`).pipe(
      tap(() => this.log('Settle deleted')),
      catchError(this.handleError<number>('DeleteSettle'))
    );
  }
```

screenshot from chrome's console

[image: chrome console]

screenshot from chrome's network tab

[image: chrome network tab]

Comment: it looks like you are using `` creating a template literal instead of single quotes ''

Comment: @Surreal I have also tried with this: this.router.navigate(['']); but id didn't help (single quotes)

Comment: does it freeze when you send it to any other route like blog or w/e?

Comment: @Surreal I edited post with screenshot from Chrome's console. Angular is getting HTTP 200 Status from back-end, redirect to home page, and then I can't do anything there (even scroll) because page freezes

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing happen to me and this was the solution I used

```
this.route.navigate([this.urlReditect]).then( result => {
            if (result) {
              location.reload();
            }
          } );
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add data-dismiss="modal" to your delete button
Like this;

```
 <button id="closeButtonId" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteSettle()" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
```

But if you want to make sure that the delete modal closes only after the delete request is completed and successful then you have to modify the logicAfterSettleDelete() method.

```
 private logicAfterSettleDelete() {
console.log(`Settle with id: ${this.settle.id} deleted!`);
 document.getElementById('closeButtonId').click()
this.router.navigate([``]); // after this redirection page freeze
```

}

The whole essence is to close the modal before navigating